# How to modify Choice parameter in all Jenkins jobs in a folder?

Tags: jenkins, parameters

I have lots of jenkins jobs in a folder having the same choice parameter in each job
I want to modify the parameter in all the jobs.
One way is to configure each job and modify through GUI.

Please Suggest any other method to update in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

Each job should have its own config xml file which you should find in Jenkins master server. Common location for Rhel server is something like /var/lib/jenkins/job/ etc....
You can write some script to modify those xml files and update choice parameter value from there instead of doing for individual jobs from UI. Once you update config.xml of individual jobs, please restart jenkins master to take change into effect.

Thanks.